# Definiteness in the {container} of {contents} construction

Tags: articles, idioms, definite-article, possessives, of-phrases

Let’s imagine the following situation: my friend gave me yesterday books. I put them into a box.

Now, I have noticed that we should name the box as

> the box of books that my friend gave me

not as

> the box of **the** books that my friend gave me

though outside the of-phrase we have to say

> the books that my friend gave me

as in

> Look! There are the books that my friend gave me.

What is the reasoning?

I think that native English speakers understand "the box of books" in "the box of books that he gave me" as a set of books which is contained in a box, books which are contained in a box, rather than a box with books. So there is no need to put "the" before "books" in "the box of books that he gave me", because "the" before "box of books" does the job ("the" refers to the books contained in the box). Am I right? Or there is a different logic behind this?

Comment: To be clear, there is nothing *wrong* with using **the** twice in your sentence. It's just not normally done because the meaning is clear enough without it and, everything being equal, it's easier to use the shorter sentence. (Incidentally, without your additional explanation, the sentence itself is ambiguous: Did your friend give you the box,  the books in the box, or both?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the phrase **box of books**, the prepositional phrase **of books** doesn't refer to *specific* books but to the *class* or *kind* of item in the box.

> A flock of geese flew overhead.

It's not a flock of ducks or a flock of blackbirds but a flock of geese.

> There was a pile of books on the desk.
>
> There was a box of books on the desk.

Even though the box contains *specific* books in your example, when indicating what kind of items the box contains, there's no need for the definite article; indeed the article would be wrong there, since it indicates specific items, not class of item. You can even express that idea adjectivally:

> Toss this book in the book box.
>
> Put this book on the book pile.

There, **the** goes with **box** and **pile**, not with **book**.  The word **book** is a noun used adjectivally there, indicating the kind of pile or the kind of box, that is, one that has books in it and one that consists of books.

P.S.

**A box of books** = a box with books in it

**A box of books he gave me** =   a box, with books in it, ambiguous with respect to whether you were given by him a box containing books, or given books by him  which were later put in a box.

**A box of the books he gave me** = a box containing *some* of the books he gave you; this is a partitive construction; the set, from which a subset is taken, consists of "the books he gave me".

Comment: Could you give me some sources that support your claim?

Comment: If your friend had given you many, many books, so that more than one box was necessary (your example says otherwise, that you put the books into "a box"), and you were giving some of these books away, you could say *This is a box of **the** books I was given.*

Comment: You wrote: "indeed the article would be wrong there, since it indicates specific items, not class of item". Does it apply only to the of-phrase? In "I like the books that he writes" we talk about a class of books rather than specific books on a desk, yet we have to use "the".

Comment: **the books that he writes** does not refer to a *class* of item but to specific or particular books, namely, those he writes.   The word *class* as I'm using it refers to an abstract category.  If you ask for "a cup of coffee" you're not referring to the contents of a particular vat or urn of dark liquid, but to the beverage in the abstract. In the same way, **box of books** does not refer to *particular* books.  If someone asks you what is in the box, you can reply simply "Books" and your answer would lack all particularity except for the *kind* of thing in the box.

Comment: If there were more boxes with the books that I was given, could I say "bring me a box of books that he gave me", without "the" before "books", when I want one of the boxes, no matter which?

Comment: That is not quite idiomatic if he has given you several boxes of books and you want one of them. A native speaker in that scenario would say *Bring me one of the boxes of books he gave me*.

Comment: I mean a situation when I got only books, not boxes, and put the books into different boxes.

Comment: If he has given you many books but they were not in boxes but on a cart of some kind, and now you want some of them, and which ones they are does not matter to you because you intend to burn them for heat so you can stay warm in a post-apocalyptic era in which Earth has frozen over, and you want those books delivered to you in a box: *Bring me a box of those books he gave me.*  You could also say **the** instead of **those**. You are referring to particular books, the ones he gave you. Maybe you don't intend to burn some other books.

Comment: What has changed that now we can use "the"? We don't think about a class of items, because it doesn't matter which books from the collection we want? But when we think about all of the books from the collection we should omit "the" in "the box of books he gave me", beacause then we think about a class of items?

Comment: As I wrote, "Maybe you don't intend to burn some *other* books".  The phrase *the books he gave me* specifies which books you want, as a group, not individual titles.  Maybe you don't want to burn books you already had in your own collection, or books given to you by your sister. You want to burn only *the books he gave me*.  You want some of those books, ***a box of** the books he gave me*.   Bring me a mug of beer.  Bring me a mug of the beer he gave me.

Comment: Don't we in "the box of books he gave me" in the initial context specify which particular books we want?

Comment: *The box of books he gave me* indicates that he gave you one box of books.  You want it.  It is a particular **box**, the one he gave you. It contains books.

Comment: No, he didn't give me the box, he gave me the books which I put into my own box. Now, I am saying "bring me the box of books he gave me". As I wrote in the initial question: "Let’s imagine the following situation: my friend gave me yesterday books. I put them into a box". "that he gave me" is about the books, not the box.

Comment: In the whole discussion I am using "that he gave me" in relation to the books, not the box, so I don't think that your orginal answer tells about my question...

Comment: Your scenario is wandering all over the place.  The facts on the ground are very important when determining whether a particular phrase means what you think it means.  Are we back now at the first example, where he gives you some books which you put in a box? Please see the P.S.

Comment: The P.S. has helped me a lot, especially the mention of the partitive construction. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

### A second "the" would be redundant

In the phrase:

> The box of books my friend gave me.

Using a single "the" means you are treating the box and its contents (the books from your friend) as a single unit or entity.

If you want refer to the box and its contents a separate entities, you would use the second "the" like so:

> The box with the books my friend gave me.

Comment: Could you give me some sources that support your claim? Your answer is consistent with my understanding of the phrase, but I have got another answer which makes sense too.